# Why is Image not shown properly as a Button background in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to convert this kv code into my own class

```
<BaseScreen>:     # This is GridLayout
    cols: 4
    rows: 4
    padding: 25
    Button:
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        Image:
            source: "business_bookcover.png"
            x: self.parent.x
            y: self.parent.y
            width: self.parent.width
            height: self.parent.height
            keep_ratio: False
```

The problem is that I'm trying to make "clickable image", but when I append widget to the button, image is on the default position (0,0), totally out of the button position. Is there any workaround how to do it?

This is my try

```
class Book(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.size_hint = (None, None)

        book_cover_image_source = kwargs.get('cover') or BLANK_BOOK_COVER

        book_cover = Image(source=book_cover_image_source)
        book_cover.pos = self.pos
        book_cover.width = self.width
        book_cover.height = self.height
        book_cover.allow_stretch = True
        book_cover.keep_ratio = False

        self.add_widget(book_cover)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kv languaje  properties used in the expression (`x:`, `y:`, `width:`) will be observed. When the parent's `size`/`pos` change, child widget change accordingly. You must suply this event bindings in the Python class:

```
class Book(Button):
    def __init__(self, cover=BLANK_BOOK_COVER, **kwargs):
        super(Book, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.book_cover = Image(source=cover)
        self.book_cover.allow_stretch = True
        self.book_cover.keep_ratio = False
        self.add_widget(self.book_cover)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.book_cover.size = self.size

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.book_cover.pos = self.pos
```

A simpler option to get a clickable image is to have your class `Book` inherit from `ButtonBehabior` and `Image` classes:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class Book(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, cover=BLANK_BOOK_COVER, **kwargs):
        super(Book, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = cover
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.allow_stretch = True
        self.keep_ratio = False
```

Comment: I've already found out a solution with ButtonBehaviour and Image, but thanks anyway!